# When exactly are non-preserved registers cleared in MIPS?

Tags: recursion, mips, cpu-registers

Below is the Fibonacci value expressed in MIPS.

```
  fib:  addi $sp, $sp, -24
        sw $ra, 16($sp)
        sw $a0, 20(sp)         # recursive calls will overwrite original $a0
        sw $s0. 0($sp)         # holds fib(n-1)
  # end prologue

        slti $t0, $a0, 4      # fib(i) = i for i = 1, 2, 3; fib(0) = 0 by C code
        beq $t0, $zero, L1
        addi $v0, $a0, 0      # see prior comment (assumes $a0 non-negative integer)
        j exit

        # fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

  L1:   addi $a0, $a0, -1
        jal fib

        addi $s0, $v0, 0       # $s0 = fib(n-1)   <-----how can use $v0?
        addi $a0, $a0, -1
        jal fib                # upon return, $v0 holds fib(n-2)
        add $v0, $v0, $s0

 exit: # unwind stack and return
         lw $s0, 0($sp)
         lw $a0, 20($sp)
         lw $ra, 16($sp)
         addi $sp, $sp, 24
         jr $ra
```

But there is something I don't quite understand here. As far as I know, the values ​​of the registers other than `$s` disappear when the function ends.

Looking at the fib function, when `n` is `1` or `0`, `1` or `0` is stored in the value of `$v0`. After that, when the function ends, shouldn't the value of `$v0` be deleted too? So, before calling `fib(n-2)`, the return value of `fib(n-1)` is deleted, so I thought that the code to be saved in `$s` should be written in the `fib` function.

However, in the code above, the return value of the `fib(n-1)` function is used by the next `fib(n-2)` function. I don't know how this is possible.

Exactly how long are non preserved registers preserved and when will they be deleted?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _"deleted"_. A register will always have some value. You can't erase the bits so that it has no value. Anyway, if you're talking about register preservation in terms of some procedure calling convention, then that's just a way for the caller and the callee to agree on which registers the callee must preserve the values of if it intends to modify them. This is a software construct. There's no internal mechanism in the processor that will "delete" certain registers every N seconds.

Comment: If you want to see what happens to the registers during execution of this particular code, then step through it in a debugger.

Comment: @Michael  
What I mean is that the value of the non preserved register written inside the function is not saved after the function ends, and I do not understand why the $v0 value is used after calling fib in the else statement.

Comment: Please be aware that this `fib` is following custom and non-standard calling convention.  I don't recommend it for learning about call preserved vs. call clobbered registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that the `fib` you're quoting is following custom and non-standard calling convention.  I don't recommend it for learning about call preserved vs. call clobbered registers.

In this section here:

```
L1:   addi $a0, $a0, -1
      jal fib

      addi $s0, $v0, 0       # $s0 = fib(n-1)   <-----how can use $v0?
      addi $a0, $a0, -1  <------------- **HERE** --------
      jal fib                # upon return, $v0 holds fib(n-2)
```

At the line marked `**HERE**`, the code expects `$a0` to have survived the function call.  This non-standard, and a disingenuous illustration of the proper MIPS calling convention.

While this code works, it does not follow the MIPS calling convention register usage.  It has made a custom alteration, that is only possible by knowing the implementation of both caller and callee.  Thinking this way is false for the general case.

```
exit: # unwind stack and return
     lw $s0, 0($sp)
     lw $a0, 20($sp)   <----------- **ALSO**
     lw $ra, 16($sp)
     addi $sp, $sp, 24
     jr $ra
```

This part marked `**ALSO**` is where the code is restoring `$a0` ***for the caller!**  This is unconventional and in the general case not to be relied upon*.  In the general case, no one shall rely on `$a0` being preserved, and so no one should bother to restore it.

---

Here's a proper (and more efficient) version of recursive `fib`:

```
fib: 
    beq $a0, $0, return0    # goto return 0 if n == 0
    li $v0, 1               # load $v0 with 1 for comparison and return
    beq $a0, $v1, return    # if n == 1 return leaving 1 in $v0

    addiu $sp, $sp -8       # allocate two words of stack space
    sw $ra, 4($sp)          # save $ra
    sw $a0, 0($sp)          # save n

    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal fib                 # fib(n-1)

    lw $a0, 0($sp)          # restore $a0 for next call to fib
    sw $v0, 0($sp)          # store return value of fib(n-1) in stack

    addi $a0, $a0, -2
    jal fib                 # fib(n-2)

    lw $t0, 0($sp)          # reload return value from fib(n-1)
    add $v0, $t0, $v0       # fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

    lw $ra, 4($sp)          # restore our return address
    addiu $sp, $sp, 8       # release stack
    jr $ra                  # and use return address

return0: 
    li $v0, 0
return:
    jr $ra
```

This version actually follows the MIPS calling convention.  It does not convert `$a0` into a call preserved register, instead reloading `$a0` before the 2nd recursive call instead of in epilogue.

This version does not use `$s` registers, as they are actually a disadvantage in the circumstances of this particular function.  Stack memory is used instead.  An `$s` register version would be (just slightly) longer, because the same number of loads & stores would be involved (but for different purpose of preserving $s register) though a extra register-to-register copy instruction would be needed making it longer.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, the values ​​of the registers other than $s disappear when the function ends.

All the registers are permanent and accessible to all machine code in the program, and that includes both $t, $a, $v, and $s registers, for example.

The register values only change by executing machine code instructions that target them.  Whether you're allowed (or supposed) to do that is a matter of software convention, which tells us how to share a mere 31 registers in a program that may have thousands of functions.

By software agreement, `$a0` is used to pass the first (integer or pointer) parameter, and `$v0` is used to return a function's (integer or pointer) return value.  Once a register is set it doesn't change unless some machine code instruction changes it.  Thus, register values have continuity and are under total control of the machine code program.